# How do I test to see if a battery is good?

Tags: battery, charging, htc, htc-evo-3d

I have had such a nightmare with sprint.

I'm not going into all the details but I ordered a battery for my htc 3d phone. I just want to get it up and running. I lost 10 days worth of texts and voicemails.

I took both my old and new batteries to Sprint and they told me they were bad, or that they weren't sure if they were bad. I then took them to a battery place that told me they were good. All they did was hook a voltmeter up to them and they all tested between 3.7 and 4.2 volts. But that doesn't tell me if they're good or not. I told the battery guy that it needs to be load tested. I'm not interested if a voltage is present and I had already done that at home.

I needed to know if there was current present. He said it would take 24 hours to load test a cell phone batter but my motorcycle battery would take 5 minutes to load test. It all sounded like a racket to me at both places who just wanted me to buy stuff.

Does anybody know how I can load test my battery at home to see if there's any current flowing through the battery? Thanks.

Comment: Get a few [LEDs](http://www.greenprophet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/LED-lights-health-hazard.jpeg), 2 jumper wires and hook the battery to an LED.

Comment: It doesn't take much current to power an LED would that be enough to start a phone? Isn't there a meter of some sort that could tell me if it's holding a charge and how much? Thanks

Comment: @Huey sorry I forgot to tag you in the above comment.

Comment: Phone batteries vary so I doubt there's an affordable tool that will simply tell you how much charge the battery has. I'm assuming you don't want to simply try using the battery for some reason. Frankly, this sounds more like an issue with that particular battery retailer or manufacturer than an android issue.

Comment: If you are DIY types, this can help https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/527 also this has some simple variations http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18612/how-to-measure-capacity-of-a-lithium-ion-battery . Posting it as answer assumes comfort level of end users with this kind of stuff, so not doing it unless you find something simple enough for you and want me to post that